# How can I include a javascript file from inside my Bundle into a twig file?

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

How can I include a javascript file from my Bundle CompetitiongameBundle, in a twig file ?
What does the asset function mean ?

Comment: I fail to see why this got voted down. Is a perfectly valid question and the symfony documentation is more on the lacking side... I would not hesitate to google before referencing to it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't you trust [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets)?

> You can also include assets located in your bundles' Resources/public folder. You will need to run the php app/console assets:install target [--symlink] command, which moves (or symlinks) files into the correct location. (target is by default "web").

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/css/contact.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I don't advice to you link against individual resources from bundle - use [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) for that, possibly minifying them.